# How To Publish Business Objects Query Service

Tags: c#, web-services, business-objects

We are trying to copy a BO Query Service from one Universe to another.  If you use the BO Query As A Service(QAAS) tool you can do this, but end up basically recreating the query service.

It seems like the BusinessObjects.DSWS.* libraries allow you to read and write query services, but those don't appear in the QAAS tool.  I think that those queries go into a different Universe than the QAAS tool pings.  Perhaps there is a Universe for data and another for Web Service Queries.  Monitoring the QAAS tool for HTTP traffic revealed that the BO Web Service used to run queries for the data they contain is also used to manage the Web Service queries.

I was able to copy one Query Service into a new one in a new Universe using a Replace() on the XML string in QuerySpec to change the UniverseID.  We can basically copy one Query Service to another Universe without manually rebuilding it except for one little thing.

The QAAS tool includes a Publish button.  This does something unknown, but important.  Perhaps it makes some SOAP, WSDL or config files so that the copied Query Service is public.  There doesn't seem to be any HTTP traffic to snoop on when it's doing this.  The BusinessObjects.DSWS.* libraries include a Publish feature, but it's not for Query Services.  It's for general files like Excel and PDF.

Right now, we are relegated to using two tools.  Does anyone know about how to Publish a BO Query Service programmatically just like the QAAS Tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while, but there was a hackish way of doing this.

You can use a VS tool to generate a csharp class that can call the BO web service.  That object can pull the relevant settings in a text format.  Then you replace the existing portion of the object IDs in the query service that is the Universe ID with a new Universe ID.  That object can then add the new query service.

This process is extremely quick and afterwords you need to use the QAAS tool to publish the new, copied query service.  All the Publish actions available from code seem to publish something else and not query services.